# Restricting Search Results based on list permissions

Tags: search

I am attempting to restrict search results based on list permissions where the user should only be able to see those items which they added.  This works in the list itself using the "Read items that were created by the user" option.  However, search does not return any results from the list while this is active for anyone other than those users who have full control.

Could someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Search crawling account only has "Full Read" Access to the content which means, with those library settings enabled, the crawler isn't finding any items in the library to crawl.

If it's an On Prem environment, you could elevate the permissions for the Search Crawling account (Central Admin --> Web Applications --> Select the web app --> User policy --> Change the permission for the Search Crawling Account.

However wouldn't recommend doing that. So probably review the security requirements for your documents and then change the settings appropriately.

Comment: Along theses lines, you could adjust the Crawl Account permissions on the list. The user ACLs will still be honored, right?

Comment: ACLs will be honoured when rendering the search results. CrawlAccount Permissions are however given at a web application level as a user policy.